# Why should or shouldn't we allow the human body to take its natural course?

Tags: human-biology, physiology

For example, when you are sick but don't feel thirsty, this could be due to baroreceptor reflex that is attempting to readjust salt and water balancing.

Why shouldn't a patient be left thirsty and let the body to adjust until he or she feels thirsty again?

Comment: Are you suggesting that we should throw away modern medicine and go back to natural selection?

Comment: I find this very unclear and broad (there are a huge number of processes and responses to consider).

Comment: imagine you have diarrhea and eventually will lose a lot of water. Would you like an IV with saline/vitamins or to be left alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your question is: "why can a human intervention improve health?". Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

**Why can a human intervention improve health?**

Let's first avoid going into the details of your example. It is quite obvious that human intervention can often improve health in a way that your body alone cannot. To me, an intuitive way to classify the reasons why human intervention are important to improve health into two categories.

1. The body does not always react in an adaptive manner.

   - Example: [Anaphylaxis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphylaxis) is a serious and sudden allergic reaction that may cause death. An allergic reaction is what is happening when your immune system recognize a chemical as a infectious element while it is not. The reaction of the body is not adaptive and taking medication such as an anti-histaminic can force the body to stop this "stupid" reaction.
   - Note: There are reasons why the body cannot be always perfect but it is a bit long to make an overview here. There is stochasticity in the developmental processes, there is genetic variation for example due to always occurring deleterious mutations, there is also an arms race between parasites and host. This arm race leads parasites to take advantage of normal host physiological pathways. There are tons of other reasons that relate to the stochasticity and to the physic and physiological constraints of evolutionary processes.
2. The body sometimes cannot (physical constraint) produce the action that is required to be performed to improve health.

   - Example:  If you have an important wound, then a human-made compression can by far improve your chance of the survival. The body is not able by itself to simulate this external compression to prevent blood to exit the body through the wound.

You might easily find semantic issues with these categories though such as the question of cancer and its removal for example and some may argue against this categorization.

**Dehydration and thirst**

Your example would fall into the first category. It is not so uncommon that the body needs water while not causing thirst. Because after 50 years old, the sensation of thirst start to diminished, dehydration without the sensation of thirst is common among old people. Dehydration along with hyperthermia is a relatively important cause of death during hot weather in summer. It is especially true in old people as the sensation of thirst diminishes with age. Dehydration following diarrhea is also a common and important issue in old people sometimes leading to death.

Comment: Dehydration/hyperthermia isn't just an issue for elderly people, it can affect anyone.

Comment: I meant that it is an issue of particular importance in old people as old people the sensation of thirst decreases with age. Feel free to edit my answer to clarify this point if it is a bit unclear.

Comment: I'd also add that many pathogens have evolved to abuse reflexes that would otherwise be beneficial. Coughing for transmission of airborne disease, fungi causing itch...

Comment: It is a good point. I felt it quite complicated to add this point without having to make consideration of the other evolutionary processes that may explain why an individual does not always react adaptively. I put all that in some kind of messy text as a "note" under the first category.